# Strong Parameters on nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hi im new to nestjs and ts to, i am trying to do a user registration using nestjs and it is working fine, dto's looks like the way to go to flow data from web to any datasource on nest.

The problem is that i have a dto with 2 fields login and password and my database schema has 3, login, password and admin(boolean).

If i do a request and validate this login and password and they are fine i just save it to the database, no problema until now.

The problem is that using DTO if i pass the admin with true the admin data flows directly to the database, ok i know i have to be responsible and remover this from the object but im kind of concerned with this being the default behavior because this can lead very easily to a security breach.

My code is:

```js
let body = {
    login: 'vinicius',
    password: 'keyboardcat',
    admin: 'true'
}

// DTO
class Login {
    login!: string;
    password!: string;
}

let data = body as Login;

console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
// => {"login":"vinicius","password":"keyboardcat","admin":"true"}
// note that the admin is on the object even so its not on DTO

// this destructuring achieves the desired behavior
const { admin, ...desiredData } = body;

console.log(JSON.stringify(desiredData));
// => {"login":"vinicius","password":"keyboardcat"} // this is the desired
```

The question is, how you guys deal with this?
Is there any better way of doing this without, i mean, without too much deviation from the default DTO that everyone uses?

Comment: You mean like a boolean send a true/false in admin? can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that everything i send via post on the body is assigned on the dto object. Its like the old times when rails was not yet with strong parameters and the mass assign caused a security breach because it was in the "allow all attributes for default"

Comment: Ok I got really confused, there is not asignation on a DTO, a DTO is like a blueprint of the parameters you need to perform an operation, to get more in context I need to know what you need to store or process in the createUser procedure maybe you can give an example

Comment: I updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is as simple as adding a parameter to the class with the @IsBolean decorator

```
@IsBoolean()
public admin!: boolean;
```

Maybe you can take a look to the class-validator [documentation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) wich is the library that NestJS uses to defining DTOs

Edit: with the changes you did in your question I understood perfectly now in the DTO part you can't do what you are planning as it is like a blueprint of the operation in the DTO you can do some form changes that comes in the body like parsing a string or converting a nested object to an specific class before the operation, depending on the complexity you want to add youu can have two aproaches: object destructuring(the one that is in the example) or create a custom pipe that does that transformation, I would recomend you use destructuring, I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: does not work, i have updated the question again trying to be more concise, sorry for your time.

Comment: Nice! realy thanks, the problem that i see is security, if someone creates a new field or update the schema with a new sensitive field chances are that he is not know where to look... because the default is to ~accept for default~...  every place that updates the schema with data comming from the web should be updated.
This looks like ten years ago when ruby on rails was in this same situation.

Comment: I can't really see the security problem, you seldom update the schema and the advantage of this architecture is that you only update the entity and the DTO, maybe inheritance can help you out have you seen the link I put in the answer?

Comment: the problem is that being a default example it will be followed by the users, and destructure all undesirable attributes is a big responsability.

Comment: what do you mean by default? you can set it as optional too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202365/discussion-between-ralphjs-and-vinicius-gati).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202371/discussion-between-vinicius-gati-and-ralphjs).